HttpClient Post Proxy
I have an issue with a simple http post call, I spent many hours searching for a solution. The solution is using a proxy. But I would like some explanation from somebody who understands this problem.
I tried to call the request from Postman and it works when proxy is enabled (this is the default behavior), when I manually disable it, it will stop working (no surprise).
Now, my problem with C# code.
Running the HTTP request from the console application works smoothly, returning the expected result.
I have an application on IIS, it's an old WCF service (don't know if it matters) but from the service, the call is not working. Firstly I have a problem with SSL, then the request returned 401 Unauthorized till I specified the default proxy.
The original code that works perfectly fine from console app
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var requestContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "xxx"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "xxx")
});

var result = httpClient.PostAsync("loginPage", requestContent).Result;

The same code is not working from my WCF app hosted on IIS. I would like to point out that I tried also different identities for application pool (all on my computer)
I changed the code to this and it start working. Obviously the Proxy was the issue, but I would like to know why, what happend here.
// 1. First thing I need to add, not so important right now
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
       | SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault
       | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

// 2. Second one - the crucial
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()
};

var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
var requestContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "xxx"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "xxx")
});

var result = httpClient.PostAsync("loginPage", requestContent).Result;

Please ignore the fact that I'm calling .Result at the end. Also, both applications are same .NET Framework
As you can see in my console app, I don't need to specify security or HTTP handler at all. My solution is working but it seems wrong to me. Is there an option, for example on the IIS side where I can specify the proxy? I made a lot of hosted API with just default HTTP clients, but never had a problem with security or proxy.
What is the reason for using a proxy in my WCF service hosted on IIS. Why do I need to specify this at all in my service? What is the difference between the console and my WCF?
Edit: I suspect Proxy, because it stops working if I remove this single line Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy(). I also tried to deploy the code. I just found that it works on a production server, I'm not aware of any proxy on my local and production server.

Is one .NET and the other .NET Framework, perhaps?

I will update my question thanks! Both are .NET Framework

The part about specifying a handler everytime you create a client: you shouldn't do that in the first place. HttpClient is supposed to live as long as the application. So you might consider injecting it or a HttpClientFactory and specify the configuration with proxy and SSL/TLS in dependency injection setup.

^^ The part about needing a proxy and special TLS/SSL setup in the first place is a separate issue.

@Fildor well, that's true! I must admit. But still, I need to specify at least once. Why?

@Fildor Yes, you are right, my bad, well the second part is the most interesting for me.

^^ "But still, I need to specify at least once. Why?" - So, I guess that's the issue you want to focus on and have addressed? Maybe point that out in the question. Not all people read the comments, too.

"Obviously the Proxy was the issue" how do you know? Did you remove just that line and not the rest? Does the system have a proxy configured? Further issues: Don't touch ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue, set the client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue instead. On .NET 4.6+ don't set SecurityProtocol, allow the system to decide the best protocol (you can't enable protocols using this anyway, only disable). Don't call .Result, do await instead.

@Charlieface thanks for the info about ServicePointManager, will explore this topic more. Yes, I tried to remove just this line, I updated my question.
